# Function FieldValue.arrayUnion() called with invalid data. FieldValue.serverTimestamp() can only be used with update() and set()

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```js
addDeposit(account, deposit) {

    let depositsDoc = this.db.collection("accounts")
                      .doc(account.id)
                      .collection("deposits")
                      .doc("deposits");

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      deposit.created_at = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();

      depositsDoc.update({
        "deposits": firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(deposit)
      })
        .then((a) => {
           resolve('success');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          reject("failed");
        });

    })
      .then((res) => {
        return res;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return error;
      })

    }
```

**Firestore with angular (Using default firebase SDK not angularfire ) **

I was trying to add timestamp to the deposit object by directly adding a "created_at" property calling the timestamp. By doing this, I am getting the error titled above. 
How can I add timestamp to a object in an array of objects in firestore?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't use `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` as the value to union (add) or remove, to or from, an array type value of a document field.  If you want to use that timestamp value, you need to pass it directly to a field you're updating or setting.  This is true for everything in the `FieldValue` class.  That class is named this way for a reason - it applies only to *field values*, not elements of arrays.  Note that nested map fields do count as field values.  Any involvement of an array in the path is not viable.

You'll have to think of another way you structure your data that meets your needs and also satisfies Firestore requirements.

Comment: Just to confirm, is not only that you can't use the serverTimestamp directly in array value, you can't use in a field of an object added to an array, can you?
My use case is an array of info points, where I would like to have a timestamp for the moment the points are updated.

Comment: @lujop I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but server timestamps only work when added as a the value of a field.  It does not work as the element of an array, but it will work as a nested map field value.

Comment: Thanks Doug, That is exactly my use case, I tried to use in a field value of an object that is added to an array using arrayUnion. Now your edit makes me clear that if there is an array involved it isn't possible

Answer (score 17):

Use this

`let deposit.created_at= firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now();`

More information can be found at https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#now

Comment: what a lifesaver. I am stumped as to why this is not the accepted answer!

Comment: This SHOULD NOT be the accepted answer, **unless you are using this in a Cloud Function in the same region than Firestore (to match server and function time zone)**
. Timestamp.now() is clientSide data and therefore can be manipulated by hackers. ServerTimestamp() is the only safe way if the code is running in clientSide.

Comment: @IgnacioBustos is correct.  This is not a "secure" way of generating a timestamp, as the client app is actually free to provide any timestamp value it wants, not specifically a server timestamp.  True server timestamp can only be computed on the server as a result of a document write where the `serverTimestamp()` token is provided as the value of a field (not as the element of an array).

Answer (score 2):

According to this page : https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1831

It is not yet supported.

but if you don't really need the time of the firebase server : you can use the classic Date object :

```
const formattedDate = data.creation_date.toDate().toLocaleDateString('fr-FR', {year:'numeric' ,month:'long' ,day:'numeric'});

query_document = <Define your document with FIREBASE>

await updateDoc(query_document, {
update_time: arrayUnion(formattedDate)
})
```