# How to add a timestamp to my array/List in firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I wish to generate a scatter plot using time on the x-axis from user generated submissions. To do so I am making a list of maps in which each map is the user submission and contains a timestamp field. The issue is that I cannot add a timestamp using the arrayUnion. This issue was mentioned in this post:

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52324505/function-fieldvalue-arrayunion-called-with-invalid-data-fieldvalue-servertime)

> You can't use FieldValue.serverTimestamp() as the value to union (add) or >remove, to or from, an array type value of a document field. If you want to >use that timestamp value, you need to pass it directly to a field you're >updating or setting.

So,to solve my problem I need to update directly the field for timestamp after I have already added some data which has a form similar to below and I only need to add to the last element/Map of my List/array of Maps but I do not know how long this list currently is:

myList[{Map1}{Map2}{Map3}...{examplefield:'Some data', timstamp:null}]

````
final Map submissionMap = submissionData.toMap();

//Running a firestore transaction...
    final DocumentReference areaDocument = Firestore.instance.document('Space/SAJJEED');
    Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction tx) async {
      DocumentSnapshot postSnapshot = await tx.get(areaDocument);
      if (postSnapshot.exists) {
//Adds the data except for the timestamp needed
        await tx.update(areaDocument, <String, dynamic>{'$status': FieldValue.arrayUnion([submissionMap])});
        //Insert Code for directly accessing the timestamp field and adding Timestamp 

      }
    });```

Any other workarounds would be appreciated as well.
````